# Шаблон типа, который наследуется от другого C++

Tags: c++, ооп, шаблоны-с++

Вроде в java такое есть, когда создается шаблонный тип (у меня это Element), который должен быть наследником другого класса/типа определенного (у меня ниже это sf::Drawable). Интересует в С++. 
Я вот тут написал. посмотрите, правильно ли? шаблон два раза объявлен и т.п. (пока еще не запускал, там надо много доделывать еще))

У меня в поле тот же шаблонный тип, который туда метод добавляет? И вообще правильно ли все чтобы вышесказанное организовать?

```
#pragma once
#include "../IDrawableInGame.h"

//все GUI-элементы для экрана
class GUI_Layer : public IDrawableInGame
{
public:
    GUI_Layer();
    ~GUI_Layer();
    template<typename Element, typename 

std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<sf::Drawable, Element>::value>::type* = nullptr>    
        void addToLayer(Element _element, sf::Vector2f position);//добавляет элемент в map

private:

    template<typename Element, typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<sf::Drawable, Element>::value>::type* = nullptr>
    std::unordered_map<Element, sf::Vector2f> elements; //структура содержит элемент GUI и его позицию
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Как я понял: Шаблонный тип `Element` должен быть наследником от `sf::Drawable`, тогда ваш класс записывается тиким образом:

```
template<class Element>
class GUI_Layer
{
    static_assert(std::is_base_of<sf::Drawable, Element>::value);
public:
    GUI_Layer();
    void addToLayer(Element _element, sf::Vector2f position);

private:
    std::unordered_map<Element, sf::Vector2f> elements
}
```